# How to include quotes in python?

Tags: python, quotes

expected result:

```
What is your name? *name*
So your name is 'name' huh?
```

code :

```
name = input("What is your name? ")
print('So your name is ' , 'name' ,'?')
```

i need help on the second line of my code!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
name = input("What is your name? ") 
print("So your name is '{0}'?".format(name))
```

To solve issues like this only both single `'` and double `"` quotes are allowed in python strings.

Also note I've use the [`string.format()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) function to format the string otherwise it would be ugly and would look like:

```
print("So your name is '" + name + "'?")
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [string formatting](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) with double quotes:

```
>>> name="user3094915"
>>> print("So your name is '%s'" % name)
So your name is 'user3094915'
```

In general, you could use `"`, `'`, `"""` and `'''` as string delimiters in Python. Whenever you need to put a quite in your string, simply delimit the string with a different type.

The other way is escaping your quotes with `\`, e.g. `\'` or `\"`. This is the classic way, and almost every other programming language uses this idiom, which arguably makes your code more readable to non-Pythonists.

Comment: user expects `name` within quotes eg: `So your name is 'user3094915'`

Comment: My bad, fixed - see full answer now.

Answer (score 1):

You can do so by adding \ before the quote..
**Code:**

```
name = input('what is your name?')
print ('so yourname is \'',name,'\'')
```

or

```
print ('so yourname is \'{0}\''.format(name))
```

Hope this helps... :)

Comment: You can mix `"` and `'` :)

Comment: Yes we can.. But that's was already answered above.. so i preferred this :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the representation function `repr` gives nicer results:

```
for name in ("ocean","guiovar'ch"):
    print ("so yourname is '{0!s}'".format(name))
    print ("so yourname is {0!r}".format(name))
    print ("so yourname is %r" % name)
```

result

```
so yourname is 'ocean'
so yourname is 'ocean'
so yourname is 'ocean'
so yourname is 'guiovar'ch'
so yourname is "guiovar'ch"
so yourname is "guiovar'ch"
```